# Codeigniter : on selection of a value from drop down change value of checkbox

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have 3 tables say:-

invoice_details, customer_details and bill_address.

The **invoice form** has a `dropdown` and a `checkbox`. `Customer names` are listed in the dropdown from the `customer table`. And when I select a `customer name` the checkbox values must have the corresponding `billId`.

so when I mark the checkbox, the value of checkbox must be the `billId` of that customer name that has been selected. I hope my question is clear.

**view page:-**

```
<div class="row space">
 <label class="control-label">Customer <span class="manda">*</span></label>
 <select class="form-control" name="customerId" id="customerId">
   <option value="0">Choose....</option>
     <?php 
      if ($customer) {

       foreach ($customer as $row) {

        echo "<option value='".$row->customerId."'>".$row->customer_name."</option>";
      }

     } ?>

     </select>
</div> 
<div class="row space">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="bill">
  <label>Bill To</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

How could I do this? please help me...

`customerId` is common in all `3 tables`.

**Table details:-**

```
bill_address(billId, customerId, street, city, state, country).
customer_details(customerId, customer_name, phone, email,..).
invoice_details(invoiceId, customerId, billId, date, status,..).
```

Comment: you know ajax in codeigniter???

Comment: have your problem is solved or not , please let me know?

Comment: yes sir, I know ajax.

Comment: yes sir, I got solution. thank you @KUMAR. But I made a few changes in code. `foreach($BillTableDta as $bill)
    {
      $billData.='<input type="checkbox" name="billcheckbox" value="'.$bill.'">';
   }` as using for each  9 check box appears i need only one to appear. its working fine.

Comment: ok , its good to hear its working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view page of Invoice Form:-**

```
<div class="row space">
 <label class="control-label">Customer Name<span class="manda">*</span></label>
 <select class="form-control" name="customerId" id="customerId">
   <option value="0">Choose Customer Name</option>
     <?php 
      if ($customer) {

       foreach ($customer as $row) {

        echo "<option value='".$row->customerId."'>".$row->customer_name."</option>";
         }
       }
      ?>

     </select>
</div> 
<div class="row space">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id='billData'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Ajax Code:-** Add this code in Invoice Form view Page before closing `</body>` Tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customerId").on("change",function(){
    var customerId = $(this).val();
 
    $.ajax({
         url : "<?php echo base_url('controler_Name/get_data_in_bill_checkbox') ?>",
         type: "post",
         data: {"customerId":customerId},
         success : function(data){
            //alert(data);
    $("#billData").html(data);
         }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

**Contoller Code:-**

```
public function get_data_in_bill_checkbox(){
    
    $customerId = $this->input->post("customerId");

    $BillTableDta = $this->db->get_where('bill_address',array('customerId'=>$customerId))->row_array();
           
           $billData = "<label>Bill To</label>";
              foreach($BillTableDta as $bill)
              {
                $billData.='<input type="checkbox" name="billcheckbox" value="'.$bill.'">';
              }
               echo $billData;
           }
```

**Note:-** For more Reference see this https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following let me know if it worked using the triangle.:-)

```
<div class="row space">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label class="control-label">Customer <span class="manda">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="customerId" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="customerId">
        <option value="0">Choose....</option>
        <?php 
            if ($customer) {

            foreach ($customer as $row) {

            echo "<option value='".$row->customerId.'/'.$row->customer_name."'>".$row->customer_name."</option>";
            }

            } 
        ?>
        </select>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['customerID'])){
        $true=checked;
        $data=explode("/",$_POST['customerID']);
        $id=$data[0];
        $name=$data[1];
        }
        else {
        $true="";
        }
    ?>
</div> 
<div class="row space">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($true){ echo $true; } ?> name="checkbox" value="<?php if(isset($id){ echo $id; } ?>"> <!-- you can change this $id to $name based on your need.-->
        <label><?php if(isset($name) { echo $name; } ?></label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am having an error. undefined id. sir @waanofii.tech both dropdown and checkbox are in a form with a submit button.

Comment: edited the answer typos error change implode to explode.and move the closing form tag to the bottom

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: manger_views/invoice.php
Line Number: 330
iam getting this error.  what should i do? @waanofii.tech

Comment: check now i have made some changes in the last section of the code on check box and values around it :-)

Comment: I got solution above code is working. Thanks @waanofii.tech

Comment: @FIDAFATHIMA glad to hear that.